# QGIS 3.26 crash with WCS render type

Tags: wcs

I am using QGIS 3.26 and it crashes (closes) when, after uploading a WCS link, I try to change the render type in Layer Styling. What could be wrong?

I am on Windows x64 and the WCS link is the following: http://portaldoclima.pt/thredds/wcs/ipmadt/ho/PT100-ho19712000-aaa-avgr-pravgr.nc?service=WCS&version=1.0.0&request=GetCapabilities

Comment: How exactly are you uploading the link?

Comment: I added a new raster WCS layer, connected to it and opened as a tiff or netcdf.

Comment: I think possibly the WCS is misconfigured.  DescribeCoverage ~ http://portaldoclima.pt/thredds/wcs/ipmadt/ho/PT100-ho19712000-aaa-avgr-pravgr.nc?service=WCS&version=1.0.0&request=DescribeCoverage&identifier=pr ~ shows invalid CRS `EPSG 0`.   Any request with a Bounding box or response CRS code such as one constructed by QGIS, will fail